# iPhone Flickr API callback URL when user fails to authorize

Tags: iphone, safari, oauth, callback, flickr

I am using flickr's API to authorize an iPhone app by following their web based applications authentication flow. If the user authorizes the application a callback URL is called and everything runs smoothly. However, if the user denies the application, the browser is forwarded to another part of flickr's site, and because we are using a browser to authenticate in the iPhone, the user remains in safari. Is there a way for my application to know that it was denied by the user, return to my application, so that I can handle the denial and/or error gracefully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the Flickr API at all and have never worked with it, but one idea that came to my mind is the following: Use an in-App UIWebView instead of safari and set the delegate property ([UIWebViewDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)). Your delegate should then implement the following method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Through the request object you can retrieve the URL being called and check whether it fits the scheme of a failed authorization URL. There might be a more elegant way to check for a failure in authentication (in fact I am pretty sure there is), yet this should work.